# Tiny question about two statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Hi I just have a tiny question so consider these statements
p = "it's a mammal", q = "it's a dog"
p -> q is just if its a mammal then its a dog
Now what if q is true(it's a dog) and p is true(if it's a dog it's obviously a mammal) then couldn't I just say p->q is then true? But that obviously also doesn't make sense because just because it's a mammal doesn't mean it has to be a dog right..? So how can the whole statement be true?

Comment: Read "if" as "whenever."

Comment: I honestly think I'm too stupid to understand logic but this just doesn't make sense to me like nothing does looking at p->q's truth table it's only false if p is true and q is false. So what if in this case p is true(it's a mammal) and q isn't true(not a dog but it could still be any other mammal) according to the truth table the whole sentence is false is it not? But that's obviously not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Without any context, “if it is a mammal, then it is a dog”, that is, $$P{\implies} Q,\tag1$$ is neither particularly meaningful (what does “it” refer to?) nor technically a proposition (which, by definition, has a definite truth value):

   if “it” refers to a dog, or a fish, then $(1)$ is a true statement; if “it” refers to a goat, then $(1)$ is false.
2. The claim that you actually mean to assert is “**for all things**,
   if it is a mammal, then it is a dog”, that is, $$\text{for all }
   x,\;\Big(P(x){\implies} Q(x)\Big).\tag2$$

   This (quantified) statement is indeed false, as per your intuition.

The issue is that your example is from *predicate logic*, which is a step up from the basic *propositional logic* that you are currently learning. The former deals with propositional functions like $P(x),$ while the latter deals with propositions like $P$ that don't involve variables.

Comment: Okay because I just saw some videos about converses and he says something like
P->Q is different from Q->P and he gives an example like mine:
If it is a dog, then it is a mammal q->p
and then If it is a mammal, then it is a dog p->q
now he says the first one is TRUE and the said the second is FALSE but to me it doesn't seem like it's ALWAYS false right? and like obviously it's false because it doesn't make sense it being a mammal doesn't automatically make it a dog but like so p->q is true if it is talking about a dog or something that is not a mammal but otherwise false right?

Comment: @jayblosem11 Yes (as illustrated in my #1 after the colon). Though I'd like to emphasise that my three examples involve six different atomic propositions $P_d,$ $P_f,$ $P_g,$ $Q_d,$ $Q_f,$ $Q_g,$ where for example, $P_f$ means "a fish is a mammal", and where none of the propositions contains the word "it". (On the other hand, you're describing your query as if you are using propositional logic to analyse predicate logic. <—Just ignore this bit if you don't understand it.)

Comment: Okay thanks but I have another question so if I have the sentence p="It is a dog" q="It is a mammal" p->q = "If it is a dog then it is a mammal" according to the truth table p->q is false if P is true and Q is false. But in this example I mean how can P ever be true and Q ever be false? If P is true then Q literally has to be true because that's just a what a dog is right like I don't even know what I'm trying to ask here but it's just Q can't be false ever if P is true in this example unless I'm not seeing something?

Comment: Also now my friend told me something and I got confused again they said that the "if it is a mammal" basically just says that IT is referring to some mammal like thats it just some mammal in general in which case this sentence is always false because just because it's a mammal doesn't mean it's a dog right

Comment: @jayblosem11 1. "for all $x,\:P(x){\implies}Q(x)$" is indeed a true sentence according to your new interpretation (assignment of meaning and thereby truth values); on the other hand, it is false according to your previous interpretation. 2. Please re-read my answer thoughtfully so that your querying/analysis will at least be more grounded. 3. A formal sentence $P{\implies}Q$ is abstract until given a concrete interpretation; its truth value corresponds to exactly one of the four lines in its truth table, *based on the assigned meanings of the symbols $P$ and $Q.$*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the truth table for $P\to Q$:

[image]

Line 1 tells us that if both $P$ and $Q$ are **true**, then the implication $P\to Q$ is also **true**.

Line 2 tells us that $P$ is **true** and $Q$ is **false**, the the implication $P\to Q$ must be **false**.

Lines 3 and 4 tell that if $P$ is **false**, then regardless of the truth value of $Q$, the implication $P\to Q$ must be **true**. (As you can see, just because the implication is true does not mean that the consequent ($Q$) is necessarily true.)

You can think of this truth table as the "definition" of logical implication, but each line can be justified by a formal proof from "first principles." See my [blog posting](https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/) on this topic (some familiarity with the basic methods of proof is required).

Comment: Right so if I have p = "It is a mammal" and q = "It is a dog" p->q = "If it is a mammal then it is a dog" now obviously just looking at this sentence it makes no sense you can't just say that a mammal is always gonna be a dog right? Idk why but I'm like so confused here this sentence just doesn't make sense you can't say it but if p is equal to what I said and q is equal to what I said then that's literally what p->q is but it's simply a sentence that isn't true or am I just misunderstanding? It is true if P and Q and true (according to the truth table)

Comment: Like so I guess if P is true and it is a mammal but then Q is false because it's not a dog or something it's just a bear the truth table will just say the whole sentence is false which is also true

Comment: An example I like to use is, "If it is raining, then it is cloudy." This does NOT mean the rain causes cloudiness. It means only that, at the present time, it is not the case that it is both raining and not cloudy. It's a single case. There is no notion of cause and effect, or any observations made over a long period of time. If it is not raining, then of course, it is not the case the it is raining and not cloudy. Now, when we say if X is a dog, then X is mammal (a single case), we mean that it is not the case that X is both a and dog an not mammal. Nothing more.

Comment: If X is both a dog and a mammal, then it is not the case that is both X is both a dog and not a mammal. We can also say that, in this one case at least, if X is a dog then X is a mammal.